# Can't seem to import queue into python

Tags: python, queue

I'm following a tutorial on how to create queues in python

But i can't get past the first hurdle:

When I try to import the queue module and try and create a queue

```
import queue

# Initializing a queue
qW = queue.Queue(maxsize=20)

# qsize() give the maxsize of the Queue
print(qW.qsize())
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'queue' has no attribute 'Queue' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Did you name your script *queue.py*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your current file or any other file in your current working directory is not named as queue.py
Python is probably importing that instead of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You likely used the same name for a file in your script folder